# Добавление авы на сайт

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

Подскажите, где можно найти статью или урок (а лучше скрипт), где объясняется, как можно добавить изображение на сервер с помощью php. Чтобы при добавлении оно обрезалось до нужной ширины и высоты. Нужно для вставки в систему регистрации.

Answer (score 3):

**GD**:

```
$src = imagecreatefromgif('sample.jpg');
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor(80, 40);

imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, 20, 13, 80, 40);

header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
imagegif($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

**Imagick**:

```
$im = new Imagick("sample.jpg");
$im->cropImageThumbnail(80, 40);
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
print $im;
$im->destroy();
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно прочитать:

1. Генерация Thumbnail очень популярный урок в свое время и познавательный был. Про обрезание картинки с масштабированием и без до определенных размеров например до 48x48.
2. Нужно просто научится загружать файлы через переменную $_FILES.

Кстати если вы использовали бы какой-то каркас приложений (Framework), то там порой уже есть библиотеки для всего этого и создание пользователя и загрузки изображений.

Делается вообще чуть ли не в три строки:

```
$userpic = Image::new( $_FILE['tmp_name'] );
$userpic->resize( 300, 300, Image::RESIZE_CORP );
$userpic->save( '...', Image::OUTPUT_JPEG );
```

P.S. Это псевдокод.

Answer (score 0):

to Alex Silaev:
Ответ, конечно, хорош. И библиотека GD в тему. Только надо не забывать, что есть ещё imagecreatefromjpeg(), imagecreatefrompng(), помимо imagecreatefromgif(). Так что советую автору, если он разбирается хоть немного в пхп, написать самому такой код. Работать надо с http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gd-info.php . Удачи в изучении!